# Populate Pandas Dataframe with normal distribution

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to populate a dataframe with numbers that follow a normal distribution.  Currently I'm populating it randomly, but the distribution is flat.  Column a has mean and sd of 5 and 1 respectively, and column b has mean and sd of 15 and 1.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 10
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
  a=np.random.randint(1,10,size=n),
  b=np.random.randint(100,110,size=n)
))
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `a=np.random.normal(5,1,size=n)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. `randint` does not select from normal dist. `normal` does. Also no idea where you came up with 100 and 110 in `min` and `max` args for `b`.

```
n = 10
a_bar = 5; a_sd = 1
b_bar = 15; b_sd = 1
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=np.random.normal(a_bar, a_sd, size=n),
                       b=np.random.normal(b_bar, b_sd, size=n)),
                  columns=['a', 'b'])
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 200
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
  a=np.random.normal(1,10,size=n),
  b=np.random.normal(100,110,size=n)
))

plt.style.use("ggplot")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df["a"])
ax.plot(df["b"], color="b")
plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

[Generated Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlmNQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the wrong numpy function: `np.random.randint` returns random integers from the **discrete uniform** distribution. If you want a random **normal** distribution, you need to use `np.random.normal`, namely:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 10
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
  a=np.random.normal(loc=5,scale=1,size=n),
  b=np.random.normal(15,1,size=n)
))
```

where `loc` corresponds to the mean value, and `scale` to the standard deviation value of the distribution.